# Create sub-directory and inserting file in it

Tags: qt

I've tried to create a folder and insert a file in it or create a file in it.
Here is a code snippit:

```
QDir dir;
QString filepath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/"
               + dir.mkdir("logs")+ "/" + "file.txt");

QFile* file = new QFile(filepath);
QTextStream stream;
stream.setDevice(file);

bool check = file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append);

if(check) {
    stream << "....text....\n";
    stream.flush();
    file->close();
}
delete file;
```

There is no any error while compiling but rather, it creates a folder without a file in it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QString filepath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/"
               + dir.mkdir("logs")+ "/" + "file.txt");
```

I suspect this line, dir.mkdir("logs"), will create directory and return true or false.
I am not sure what will be your final path.

I would suggest following.

```
if(!dir.mkdir("logs")){
//error
return ;
}

QString filepath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/"
                   + "logs"+ "/" + "file.txt");
...
```

Comment: Well, you advice to create a sub-directory first and then to set a path of file?

Comment: Yes, create the subdirectory first, check that it was created correctly and then use the path. WHEN IN DOUBT, READ THE MANUAL.

Comment: I advice to first create the directory and then change the way you create path, currently you are adding dir.mkdir("logs") to path, this does not return string, it return true/false, that mean you will get wrong path.